# Rectangular Clipped Segments

Tags: r, clip, lidr, segment

I am trying to create four separate clipped quadrants to my full .laz file (See Figure 01).  I was able to clip one quadrant of (number 03 in figure 01), but am struggling to identify points to clip to create the other three quadrants of the .laz file.  Below is the code I used to create the initial clipped 03.

[image]

```
# Calculate the midpoint of the bounding box
midpoint_x <- (bbox$xmax + bbox$xmin) / 2
midpoint_y <- (bbox$ymax + bbox$ymin) / 2

#Plot and Clip first quadrant 03
plot(clip_rectangle(las, bbox["xmin"], bbox["ymin"], midpoint_x, midpoint_y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4 quadrants are

1. xmin midpoint_y midpoint_x ymax
2. midpoint_x midpoint_y xmax ymax
3. xmin ymin, midpoint_x midpoint_y
4. midpoint_x ymin xmax midpoint_y